How to Create a new Calculated Card Visualization that displays a value derived from these two cards in my dashboard in Power BI?
How to Create a Calculated Card Visualization in Power BI?
I have two card visualizations in Power BI, and I want to create a third card visualization that displays a value derived from these two cards. Additionally, the value in the new card should dynamically update based on slicer selections. How can I achieve this?
Details:
Card 1: Displays a numerical value from my dataset.
Card 2: Displays another numerical value from my dataset.
New Card: This should display a calculation based on the values in Card 1 and Card 2 (e.g., the sum, difference, ratio, etc.).
I want the value of the new card to update automatically when a slicer is used to filter the data.
Using a card visualization is not essential; I just want to display a number. However, I prefer a card visualization because it looks better on the dashboard.
What I’ve Tried:
I attempted to use DAX formulas to create a new measure, but I’m not sure how to reference the values from the existing cards or ensure that the new card updates dynamically with slicer selections.
Example:
If Card 1 shows the total sales and Card 2 shows the total cost, I want the new card to display the profit (Total Sales - Total Cost).
The profit should update when I apply a date range filter using a slicer.
Thank you.

Create 3 measures as below-
Card 1:
totalSales = sum(yourTableName[yourSalesColumnName])

Card 2:
totalCost = sum(yourTableName[yourCostColumnName])

Card 3:
totalProfit = [totalSales] - [totalCost]

